# Configurable product and associated products are in stock. Associated products have quantity > 0, still showing Out of Stock in front end.

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, stock

Configurable product and associated products are in stock. Associated products have **quantity > 0**, still showing Out of Stock in front end.

The products instock and qty values are updated programmatically over cron.

The settings from the magento backend seems to be correct:
a. Manage stock is set to yes
b. Configurable product and its associated products are set to 'In Stock'

**Magento version: 1.9.2.4**

General settings:
[image]
Configurable product:
[image]

Associated product:
[image]

What might be the issue?

Comment: Did you manually reindex stock ? Flush cache ?

Comment: i try it but not display the in-stock